# MKStoreKit Auto Renewing Subscription Expiry Date Always Returns Current Date

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, in-app-purchase, auto-renewing, mkstorekit

Using MKStoreKit for an auto-renewing subscription.  Successful purchase in the sandbox. The issue is the purchase date and expiry date always log as the same, or 1hr behind the current date.  With [accelerated sandbox times](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev7e89e149d) I would expect `[[MKStoreKit sharedKit] expiryDateForProduct:@"211112"];` to be around 30mins ahead of `[NSDate date]` on purchase as its a six month purchase. I get the current date exactly 1hr behind for the transaction.

**Log for purchase:**

```
Transaction date is 2021-07-30 4:15:07 pm +0000
Subscription end date is Fri Jul 30 17:15:07 2021
```

On reloading, the logs print that that subscription expiry date and current date are both exactly the same

**Log for reloading:**

```
 1.  Current time and date:  Fri Jul 30 17:02:42 2021
 2.  Expiry date for subscription 6 months = Fri Jul 30 17:02:42 2021
```

From the code in MKStoreKit, it would seem the purchase date may be returning NULL and returning the current date

```
-(NSDate*) expiryDateForProduct:(NSString*) productId {

  NSNumber *expiresDateMs = self.purchaseRecord[productId];
  if ([expiresDateMs isKindOfClass:NSNull.class]) {
    return NSDate.date;
  } else {
    return [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[expiresDateMs doubleValue] / 1000.0f];
  }
}
```

`[[MKStoreKit sharedKit] valueForKey:@"purchaseRecord"]` returns `<null>` on purchase

Answer (score 0):

It was incorrect app secret in `MKStorekitConfigs.plist`